# Bind please select on top of dropdown list using jquery ajax

Tags: c#, jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc

Bu using jquery Ajax post method I am calling my action method , fetching records from the data base and displaying them in a dropdown list. Everything is working fine. But I want to show "Please select" as the first option in the dropdown list. I tried everything but nothing is working in my favor. Any help would be very much appreciated. Below is my code :

.cshtml :

```
<select id="ddlChannelGroupType" name="ddlChannelGroupType">

    </select>
```

jquery ajax call to fetch the records from database :

```
   $(document).ready(function () {

        var funcareakey = @ViewBag.UserFuncAreaKey

        $.ajax(
                       {
                           type: "POST",
                           url: "/MappingChannelGroup/GetCHGRPTYPE/",
                           data: {
                               userFunctionalAreaKey: funcareakey
                           },
                           success: function (data) {

                               var items = "";

                               $.each(data, function (i, item) {

                                   items += "<option value='" + item.channelgrptypekey + "'>" + (item.channelgrptype) + "</option>";

                               });

                               $("#ddlChannelGroupType").html(items);

                           }

                       });

    });
```

My Action method on the Controller :

```
public JsonResult GetCHGRPTYPE(int userFunctionalAreaKey)
    {
        List<ChannelGrpTypeVM> objCHGRPMST = MappingChannelToGroupRepository.GetChannelGrpTypeByFuncArea(userFunctionalAreaKey);
        return Json(objCHGRPMST);
    }
```

My Logic on the repository :

```
public static List<ChannelGrpTypeVM> GetChannelGrpTypeByFuncArea(decimal funcareakey)
    {
        BarcDataContext bc = new BarcDataContext();

        var query =
                        (from CHM in bc.XREF_CH_GRP_MST
                         join CGT in bc.REF_CH_GRP_TYPE on CHM.CH_GRP_TYPE_KEY equals CGT.CH_GRP_TYPE_KEY
                         where CHM.SRC_FUNC_KEY == funcareakey
                         select new ChannelGrpTypeVM
                         {
                             channelgrptype = CGT.CH_GRP,
                             channelgrptypekey = CGT.CH_GRP_TYPE_KEY

                         }).Distinct().OrderBy(m => m.channelgrptype).ToList();

        return query;
    }
```

Comment: I don't see any logic in regards to pre-selecting one of the options.  You say everything is working except that.  I take it the dropdown is indeed building correctly?

Comment: Currently it is displaying the first record in the dropdown list by default. I want to show the "Pleas select" text first and when the user clicks the dropdown list then it populates the record.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add default value before $.each

```
success: function (data) {
   var items = "";
   items += "<option value='' disabled selected>Please select</option>";
   $.each(data, function (i, item) {
         items += "<option value='" + item.channelgrptypekey + "'>" + (item.channelgrptype) + "</option>";
   });
   $("#ddlChannelGroupType").html(items);
}
```

Comment: @N2J Try
  <option value='' disabled selected style='display: none;'>Please select</option>
  if you don't want to see it in the list

Answer (score 2):

just change your js:

```
 // this line
 items += "<option selected='selected' value=''>Please select</option>"; 
 $.each(data, function (i, item) {
    items += "<option value='" + item.channelgrptypekey + "'>" + (item.channelgrptype) + "</option>";
    });   
    $("#ddlChannelGroupType").html(items);
```

Comment: Or just put that in the html and use append() instead of html() in the logic.

Comment: This also worked , but added showing the please select text in the last.

Answer (score 0):

Try to add non displayed option and select it using JS (or default property).

```
<select default='some-id' id="ddlChannelGroupType" name="ddlChannelGroupType">
    <option value='some-id' className='display-none'>Please Select</option>
    { another options }
</select>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<label>select city:</label>
<select  id="field4">
     <option value="1">  tehran</option>
      <option value="2">  rasht</option>
 </select>

    <label>select Village:</label>
    <select class="form-control maxwidth350 " id="field5">
      <option value="1">khoshkebijar</option>
        
    </select>
```

---js---

```
<script>

    $('#field4').on('change', function() {
        if (this.value==1) 
    {
        
        $("#field5").html=('');
    
        optionostan='<option value="1">test1</option>'
        $("#field5").append(optionostan);
    }
    else if (this.value==2) 
    {
        optionostan='<option value="2">test2</option>'
        $("#field5").append(optionostan);
    }
    });
</script>
```